# How can I convince myself of this simple and obvious fact

Tags: polynomials

So my text book defined polynomials as expressions of the form: $$\mathcal{P}(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x^{1}+a_{0}x^{0}$$

And it even called $a_{0}$ a coefficient. And in one exercise they ask to calculate $\mathcal{Q}(0)$ where $\mathcal{Q}(x)=6x^2+x-7$ but that's impossible since according to the definition $\mathcal{P}(0)$ is undefined since $0^{0}$ is undefined. So we should rather define polynomials as $$\mathcal{P}(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x^{1}+a_{0}$$
where $a_{0}$ is a constant.

What do you think?

Comment: $0^0$ is only undefined if it hasn't been defined. It is not uncommon that it is defined (as $1$).

Comment: Here $\,x^0 $ denotes $1$. So evaluating it yields $1$.

Comment: A common convention in discrete mathematics (as opposed to say calculus) is to take $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: $x^0$ denotes $x$ to the zeroth power which is undefined in case of $0$. And $0^{0}$ is undefined because $0/0$ is undefined since $$0^{0}=0^{1-1}=\frac{0^1}{0^1}undefined!$$

Comment: @user126208 You seem to be confusing the powering *operation* in a ring/monoid with an (real-valued) exponential *function.* They are not the same. The power function in a monoid is defined recursively by $\, a^0 = 1,\,\ a^{n+1} = a a^n.\,$ In particular, in your case $\,x^0 = 1\,$ by *definition*. So the "value" $0^0$ never arises when evaluating polynomials. Also the monomials $\,x^n\,$ are not generally *functions*, e.g. $\,x^2 = x\,$ as *functions* on $\,\Bbb Z/2\,$ but not as *formal* polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textbook defines a polynomial as:
$$\mathcal{P}(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x^{1}+\color{red}{a_{0}x^{0}}$$

Normally, a polynomial is defined as:
$$\mathcal{P}(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x^{1}+\color{red}{a_{0}}$$

Where, as you may notice, the striking difference is the omission of $x^0$, which we're allowed to do because we define $x^0$ as $1$. (Remember that $ax =a$ iff $x=1$ or $a=0$.) Consequently, in this context, we define $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: So can I defined $0^0$ to be $2$?

Comment: No, any number $n^0$ is 1.

Comment: It's not that we define $0^0$, per se. Rather, we change the definition of "polynomial" in the case where $x = 0$. This hassle can be avoided by simply using the alternative definition provided in this answer.